# Div table, need 1 row to extend to full width in between other rows

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

I am struggling with a table (made of divs). I need the row in the middle to extend to the full width of the table and with text in the center of the row (not the cell).

I do NOT want the whole thing to `overflow-x`. And independently of the length of the text in this extended row, the width of the two main columns should not change.

So, basically, I would like an independent div, that needs to be inside the table.
How can I achieve that?

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.divTableCellExtended {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        some random text here
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        some random text here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCellExtended">
        some random text here long enough to extend out of single cell
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="divTableCell">
        some random text here
      </div>
      <div class="divTableCell">
        some random text here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrg91gaw/)

Comment: Any reason you're using `div` with `display: table`? Would you be open to changing this?

Comment: I'm using that because I want the table to always take the full width of the page. If I can keep this behavior, I am open to changing that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem:

You want to take advantage of `display:table`/`<table>` element's property of auto-adjusting width of cells across the same column, depending on content, but you want to display them responsively on narrow devices.

If you use `<div>` elements and try to implement `display:table` on them, everything works fine until you need [`colspan`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-td-element:global-attributes), because **colspan does not have a CSS equivalent** to implement with `display:table-cell;` on non-table elements.

So you need to do it the other way around: keep `<table>` elements, use `colspan` on the `<td>`s where you want it to apply and enforce `display:block` on narrow devices.

Proof of concept:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
@media (max-width:660px) {
  /* change the breakpoint to whatever you need. 660px is just an example */
  .table,
  .table tbody,
  .table thead,
  .table tfoot,
  .table tr,
  .table td,
  .table th {
    display: block;
  }  
  .table td {
    margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  }
  .table tr {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}
/* rest is just styling. ignore */
body  {background-color: #eee;}
.table {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 14px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)
}
.table td {
  border-color: #ddd;
  background-color: white;
}
@media(max-width: 660px) {
  .table {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .table tr {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 14px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table" >
  <tr>
    <td>1.1 some random text here</td>
    <td>1.2 some random text here</td>
    <td>1.3 some random text here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">2. some random text here, expanding across 3 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 3 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 3 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 3 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 3 columns and wrapping up, like it should...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.1. some random text here, in 1 column and wrapping up, like it should...</td>
    <td colspan="2">3.2. some random text here, in 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">4.1. some random text here, in 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should... some random text here, expanding across 2 columns and wrapping up, like it should...</td>
    <td>4.2. (or 4.3. - what is it?) some random text here, in 1 column and wrapping up, like it should...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you were open to not using table layout if possible to keep full width of `table`. So i've come with this 'solution'. I'm not sure that it solves your case but I hope it helps to point you in the right direction.

Edit: Fixing (partially, still loses alignment on small widths) the `width` problem so that extra *content* wont push up the columns on the sides. (add `flex-basis: 0` to **.cell** styling).

**Edit2** Perhaps you could take a look on other (and more complete) content about flex-box and responsive tables if you happen to use this kind of solution.

[CSS-Tricks article about responsive tables with flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/)

```css
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-top: none;
}

.row:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

.cell {
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.cell:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1,1</div>
    <div class="cell">Large content should not be able to push up columns on the side...</div>
    <div class="cell">1,3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">2,1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">3,1</div>
    <div class="cell">3,2</div>
    <div class="cell">3,3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution breaks the advantage of aligned "cells" across multiple columns, which is the whole point of using `display:table` or `<table>` elements in the first place. The operation was a success, but the patient is dead.